# Using Apps Script with Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Good day all,

I have a Google Form that feeds responses to a spreadsheet. The form is editable. I want each modification to create a new record, instead of updating the previous record. This is my code:

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {

  var spreadsheetId = 'YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID';  // Replace with the actual ID of your spreadsheet

  var tabName = 'TabB';

  // Open the spreadsheet and select the specified sheet

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(tabName);

  // Append the form responses to the specified sheet

  sheet.appendRow(e.values);

}
'''

Any suggestions?

I have tried several variations of this code.
```

Comment: That works for me.  Are you sure you create a trigger.  There are to on Form Submit triggers one for form and one for spreadsheet.

Comment: This is my code:`function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var spreadsheetId = gobj.globals.test1id;
  var tabName = 'Sheet0';
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(tabName);
  sheet.appendRow(e.values);
}`

Comment: @Cooper this sounds like an answer.

Comment: @Tedinoz Possibly but I haven't received any feedback from the op so I don't know.

Comment: Thank you for responding, Cooper! Yes, I created the trigger in both Sheets and Forms. This is the code I put into Forms, and it is not creating a new form submitted row for every appended record.

Comment: Hi Simon, FYI: "If you are replying to someone who has previously commented on the same post, mention their username, such as @Cooper. While entering or editing a comment, typing "@" will provide a list of users you can notify. Clicking a username from the list will automatically fill out the @ reply so you don't have to enter it manually. This will create a notification in that user's global inbox so that they know that you have replied to them."

Comment: `This is the code I put into Forms` - Take a look at the documentation for `Triggers` and `Event Objects` [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). There two `onFormSubmit` triggers (one for Sheets, one for Forms) AND each trigger has different Event Objects: [Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1) and [Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit). Your situation is very common: using the wrong trigger and the wrong event objects.